# Что означает ошибка запроса к серверу android retrofit?

Tags: android, get, retrofit

У меня во время запроса к серверу вывело ошибку:

```
"message": "invalid_parameter_value"
```

если я правильно понял, то это значит что серверу не подошло значение параметра который прописан в интерфейсе. Код интерфейса:

```
    Call<MessageAnswer> getInMess(@Query("count") Integer method);
```

и дальше я инициализировал этот интерфейс:

```
public void info() {
        Integer a = 100;
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        mAPIService.getInMess(a).enqueue(new Callback<MessageAnswer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MessageAnswer> call, Response<MessageAnswer> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MessageAnswer> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

если честно я не очень понимаю какой именно параметр нужно вставлять в инициализацию, вообще этот параметр означает кол-во входящих сообщений. Я соответственно вставил значение для пробы, если честно я не сильно понял что там должно быть, вроде как написано int но число не подходит. Если кто заметил где я ошибся то буду благодарен если укажете на мою ошибку.

Comment: Видимо вам необходимо вместо слова "TYPE" в вашем запросе указать какой-то конкретный тип.

Comment: та я его просто стер, теперь ковыряюсь что-бы можно было вставить токен программно. А то вручную как-то не очень удобно)) спасибо за совет.